# polygon Self intersection find in arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects

how to get self intersection polygons in arcobjects could you please tell me how to get already i got self intersection for polyline features as per below code but it is not working on polygon features

```
if (intF.Shape.GeometryType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline)
{
    IPolyline pline = intF.Shape as IPolyline;
    ITopologicalOperator3 ptopo = pline as ITopologicalOperator3;
    esriNonSimpleReasonEnum reasen = esriNonSimpleReasonEnum.esriNonSimpleSelfIntersections;
    ptopo.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
    if (!ptopo.get_IsSimpleEx(out reasen))
    {
    if (reasen == esriNonSimpleReasonEnum.esriNonSimpleSelfIntersections)
    {
        selfinterfind = true;
    }
    }
    if (selfinterfind == true)
    {
    dt.Rows.Add(intF.OID, intF.Class.AliasName, "", "Self Intersection Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? what happens when it doesn't work for polygons? The ITopologialOperator3 is implemented for polygons so I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Michael above code for self intersections for polyline this code i have using on self intersection polygons also is it work on polygons could you please tell me

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't. If you have any problems self intersection is a boundary problem so turn your polygon into a polyline using ITopologicalOperator.Boundary and process as before (as a polyline).